# Most appropriate run-time formula in terms of primitive operations needed for input of size n

Tags: algorithm, big-o

For the following block of code, select the most appropriate run-time formula in terms of primitive operations needed for input of size n:

When resolving from inside out, i get:

inner loop = 3n+1

main loop + inner loop = 3 + (3n +1) + logn = 4 + 3n + logn

extra steps + all loops = 4 + n(4 + 3n + logn) = 4 + 4n + 3n2 + logn

This is the code to analyze:

```
def rate(n):
    total= 0
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        j = 0
        while j < n:
            total= i * j + total
            j = j + 1
        i = i * 2
    return total
```

and the answer is supposed to be --> f(n) = 4 + 4log(n)  + log(n)*(3n)

Answer (score 2):

I am actually coming up with `O(NlgN)` here for the overall running time.  Appreciate that the inner loop in `j` is not dependent on the outer loop in `i`.  The following should be true:

- The outer loop in `i` is `O(lgN)`, because `i` is doubling at each iteration, which is exponential behavior.
- The inner loop in `j` is `O(N)`, because `j` cycles from 0 to `N` at each iteration, regardless of the value of `i`.

We may therefore multiply together these complexities to get the overall complexity.

Note that for `N` of arbitrarily large size, your expression:

```
4 + 4log(n) + log(n)*(3n)
```

reduces to `NlgN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def rate(n):
    total= 0     
    i = 1
```

> ```
>     while i < n: //This outer loop runs O(log(n)) times
> ```

```
        j = 0
```

> ```
>         while j < n: //This inner loop runs O(n) times for each iteration of outer loop
> ```

```
            total= i * j + total
            j = j + 1
        i = i * 2
    return total
```

Hence, the total runtime complexity for your implementation in big-O is = **O(log(n)) * O(n)** = **O(nlog(n))**.